# Changes are not getting reflected in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift

Right now i'm committing the application changes in 2 places.

1. git hub repository
2. openshift git hub repository

I made couple of changes to git repository as well as to openshift git repository but the changes are not being

Example git repository: https://github.com/ramkumar/test 
Example openshift repository: ssh://12131212000005@testing.rhcloud.com/~/git/test.git

```
Questions:
1. In which tomcat folder i need to check whether the files are updated? i
   check in app-root and app-deployments (repo-target-test-pages- 
   display.html) and it is having the latest files but this is not being used 
   in the application. when i removed the files still sees the application 
   is working successfully without any issues.

 2. Do we need to always commit in 2 places? Is there a way the openshift 
    automatically takes the git repository and use the same? In heroku the 
    changes are being automatically incorporated as Git hub can be directly 
    associated.
```

I have the access to folder via putty login

I have the access to the openshift console and make changes as well.

Please guide me on how to resolve the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you improve your chances having this answered if you provide more detailed description of what you push exactly (seems like you're pushing source files to a Tomcat app; there are more [deployment options](https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/deployment-options.html)) and what is the output when you push in the OpenShift repo (could the Maven build be failing, so the older working deployment is still in use?)

Comment: I have pushed the source files to git hub repository as well as git repository in openshift. the push is success and maven worked fine. i would like to know under which directory the files will be placed and how to navigate to the exact tomcat and project folder ??